# Where does the Jenkins Windows installer put java?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed the Jenkins MSI sliently

```
c:\windows\temp\jenkins.msi /qn /L*V c:\windows\temp\jenkins.log
```

Seems to be running OK, but it appears java is not in the system PATH. Where does the MSI put java?

Edit: 
I'm asking this because I want to install plugins like this:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ install-plugin http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/aws-lambda/0.5.5/aws-lambda.hpi
```

I can't run this command because I don't know where to java exe is

Comment: how can you start the jenkins install before the jdk install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It puts it here: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe'